# Why are some Vulkan extensions available through dynamic linking, but not others?

Tags: vulkan

I've been trying to write Vulkan bindings for a language and I'm a bit confused about how extensions work. On Linux I'm using libdl to load function pointers from `libvulkan.so.1`, and I've noticed that some extension functions (like those from `VK_KHR_swapchain` and `VK_KHR_Wayland_Surface`) can be linked through libdl, but others (like the ones in `VK_EXT_debug_utils` or `VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state2`) can only be found through `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` or `vkGetDeviceProcAddr`.

My questions are these:

1. Why are some Vulkan extensions available through dynamic linking but not others?
2. Can I rely on these dynamically-linkable extensions always being there? (For example, can I be sure that if the `VK_KHR_swapchain` extension is available, `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` will definitly be found by libdl?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TFM](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/main/docs/LoaderApplicationInterface.md#vulkan-direct-exports):

> ### Vulkan Direct Exports
>
> The loader library on Windows, Linux, Android, and macOS will export all core Vulkan entry-points and all appropriate Window System Interface (WSI) entry-points. This is done to make it simpler to get started with Vulkan development. When an application links directly to the loader library in this way, the Vulkan calls are simple trampoline functions that jump to the appropriate dispatch table entry for the object they are given.

Specifics: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/main/docs/LoaderApplicationInterface.md#wsi-extensions

Comment: Not sure why I had such a hard time finding that.  Thanks :)